# Alternative for Apache directive MaxRequestsPerChild in the Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6

In Apache I can set maximum number of requests which an individual child server will handle using *[MaxRequestsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild)* directive in httpd.conf file.
How can I do the same for Apache Tomcat using xml config files (server.xml, web.xml, etc.)? I'm using Apache Tomcat 6.0.43.

I'll be very thankful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tomcat has similar directive as Apache 'MaxRequestsPerChild'. In-fact tomcat don't manage requests with multiple child workers.

In Tomcat, this is managed by executor threads & Connectors. Below are few parameters that can be tuned related to max requests your JVM can handle.

Executor: maxThreads, minSpareThreads, maxIdleTime, etc., 
Connector: acceptCount.

Please refer to tomcat documentation for more details relates to these attributes.